# Can I contribute to an IRA without any U.S. earned income?

Tags: united-states, taxes, ira, contribution

I used to live in the U.S. on a H-1B and returned to my home country in the year 2017. However, I still have some U.S. ETFs and equities in a brokerage account. I also have a IRA account. I have no other sources of U.S. income.

I was wondering if I could take the dividends from my holdings as well as any capital gains I get from selling the equities and put it into the IRA (under the $5500 limit) and avoid paying taxes on the dividends and capital gains?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. IRA contributions need to come from taxable *earned* income (called taxable *compensation* below), not from passive income such as interest, dividends, capital gains, pensions etc.

From the IRS: [Retirement Topics - IRA Contribution Limits](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/plan-participant-employee/retirement-topics-ira-contribution-limits)

> For 2015, 2016, 2017 and 2018, your total contributions to all of your
>   traditional and Roth IRAs cannot be more than:
>
> - $5,500 ($6,500 if you’re age 50 or older), or
> - **your taxable
>     compensation for the year, if your compensation was less than this
>     dollar limit.**

while this next quote mentions Roth IRAs it applies to both types of IRAs.

> **[Can I Invest in a Roth With Just Dividend Income?](https://finance.zacks.com/can-invest-roth-just-dividend-income-1230.html)**
>
> Roth IRAs hold several advantages over traditional IRAs. However, **both
>   types of IRAs require earned income for contribution eligibility**, so
>   if your earnings are strictly from dividend income you cannot invest
>   in a Roth IRA. If you and your spouse file jointly and one of you has
>   earned income, you can both contribute to Roth IRAs, as long as you
>   meet the annual income limitations. **For IRA purposes, earned income
>   includes wages, salary, tips, commissions and bonuses.**